# mapview working in india but not in switzerland

Tags: android, maps

I am making an android  app in which i am using google maps which are working perfectly in India but the same build is not working in Switzerland i.e. in switzerland the maps are not loading in.
Is ther anything that is country orregion specific in generating google api key or debug.keystore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is ther anything that is country orregion specific in generating google api key or debug.keystore.

No. The `debug.keystore`, by default, is developer-specific. Hence, the Google Map API key is developer-specific. Geography has nothing to do with it.

If this is the same exact APK file being used by both devices, then either:

- The Swiss device lacks an Internet connection, or
- The Swiss device is having difficulty reaching the Google Maps servers (e.g., they are on WiFi and there is some firewall or proxy issue), or
- The Swiss device does not have really have Google Maps (e.g., it is a device with a pirated Maps app and lacks a working Google Maps API add-on for Android), or
- The Alps were bulldozed and replaced by large black gridlines, so the map is being shown accurately

The first two should be testable by the user (e.g., try opening the native Maps application or browser). The last one should be testable by having the user look out a window. :-)

If, however, the APK file was built by one developer in India and a different APK file was built by a developer in Switzerland, and the app is working in India, then the Swiss developer needs to supply his or her own Maps API key into the source code, or use the same `debug.keystore` as is being used by the developer from India.

Comment: the apk file was developed in India and the  same apk is tested in Switzerland